# Get list files in directory from service

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a saved treeuri that I get like this in MainActivity.kt

```
    fun openDirectory(pickerInitialUri: Char) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent,1001)
        }
```

when the button is pressed.

Accordingly, after that, if I understand correctly, the program has full access to the directory
I plan to save the uri to a string in the settings and use it after that.
I also have a service that periodically has to go to this directory and check for the presence of a file by mask

I'm just trying to get a list of files in the directory from the service with saved treeuri

```
      fun openDirectory() {
            val treeUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary/blablabla")

            var mContext: Context = getApplicationContext()
            val pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(applicationContext, treeUri)


            val file = File(treeUri.getPath())
            val files = file.listFiles()


            if (files != null) {
                Log.d("FilesFromService", "Size: " + files.size)
                for (i in files.indices) {
                    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].name)
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get error "requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT"

Comment: "I have a saved treeuri" -- depending on how you are defining "saved", [you might need to take some steps that perhaps you missed](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you should take persistable uri permission before you save your uri. Otherwise you cannot use it later.

Second: dont mess around with the Files class.

Use DocumentFile.listFiles() to get a listing.

`pickedDir.listFiles();`